# How to update multiple duplicates with different values on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

The table I am dealing with has multiple rows which have the same values for `lat` and `lon`. The example shows that `1`, `3`, `5` have the same location but the `name` attribute differs. The `hash` is built from `name`, `lat` and `lon` and differs therefore.

```
BEFORE:

 id | name | lat | lon | flag | hash
----+------+-----+-----+------+------
 1  | aaa  | 16  | 48  |  0   | 2cd       <-- duplicate
 2  | bbb  | 10  | 22  |  0   | 3fc
 3  | ccc  | 16  | 48  |  0   | 8ba       <-- duplicate
 4  | ddd  | 10  | 23  |  0   | c33
 5  | eee  | 16  | 48  |  0   | 751       <-- duplicate
```

I need to identify "duplicates" within this table and want to assign the flag `1` (*primary*) to one of them and the flag `2` (*secondary*) to the others. It is not important which "duplicate" is flagged as *primary*.

```
 AFTER:

 id | name | lat | lon | flag | hash
----+------+-----+-----+------+------
 1  | aaa  | 16  | 48  |  1   | 2cd       <-- updated
 2  | bbb  | 10  | 22  |  0   | 3fc
 3  | ccc  | 16  | 48  |  2   | 8ba       <-- updated
 4  | ddd  | 10  | 23  |  0   | c33
 5  | eee  | 16  | 48  |  2   | 751       <-- updated
```

I started experimenting with `INNER JOIN` [inspired by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/356895) and this [visual description](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). With this I am able to assign the same flag to all duplicates.

```sql
UPDATE table t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2
ON
  t1.lat = t2.lat
  AND t1.lon = t2.lon
  AND t1.hash != t2.hash
SET
  t1.flag = 2;
```

I also tested `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `WHERE t2.id IS NULL` which could work when there are only two rows.  However, I cannot think my head off how a `JOIN` should work with **more then two duplicates**. Mark Harrison also assumes *"that you're joining on columns with no duplicates"* [at the beginning of his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/356895) which sound as if this is not a good idea.

I am using MySQL if this is of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is very efficient, but it [works in just one query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/091ec/2):

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(t.id) AS maxid, lat, lon
  FROM t
  JOIN t AS duplicates
  USING (lat, lon)
  GROUP BY lat, lon
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS maxima USING (lat, lon)
SET flag = IF(id = maxid, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Works really fast! Thank you. Though, *SQL Fiddle* does not load for me (neither [the example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#viewSample)).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all canonical records to have a `flag=1` (and not just those records that have duplicates) you can do:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.flag = 1
WHERE t1.id in (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.lat = t2.lat
    AND t1.lon = t2.lon
);

UPDATE table
SET flag = 2
WHERE flag is null;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Only duplicates should be updated. The statement you posted throws `Mysql2::Error: You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps:

```
update table t1 set flag = 2 where id in 
   (select a.id
    from 
        t1 a
        join t1 b on (b.lon = a.lon and b.lat = a.lat));

update table t1 set flag = 1 where id in 
   (select a.id 
    from t1 a
    where a.flag = 2 and a.id = 
        (select min(b.id) from t1 b where b.lon = a.lon and b.lat = a.lat)
   );
```

This should be used as inspiration and *not* as gospel (it's probably wrong) :)