# Update Duplicates in SQL Server without a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need an update statement to resolve some issues with duplicates in a table on SQL Server 2000.  The table structure is shown below.  There is no primary key in this table.  I need a SQL statement that will update the values in cases where there are duplicates by adding 5 to the value until there are no more duplicates.

```
DocNumber       SeQNumber
Doc001           900
Doc001           900
Doc001           900
Doc001           903
Doc001           904
```

Desired Result

```
DocNumber       SeqNUmber
Doc001           900
Doc001           905
Doc001           910
Doc001           903
Doc001           904
```

This is what I have tried 
My latest attempt is shown below.  In that example I am just adding the counter, but the +5 is what I actually need.

```
Declare @count as integer = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES
FROM            dbo.RM10101
GROUP BY DocNumbr, SeqNumbr
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1))


Declare @counter as integer =1
While @Counter < @count
begin
With UpdateData  As
(
SELECT  DocNumbr,SeqNumbr,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SeqNumbr] DESC) AS RN
FROM RM10101
)
UPDATE  RM10101 SET SeqNumbr = (select max(SeqNumbr) from RM10101 where docNumbr =          RM10101.DocNumbr and SeqNumbr=RM10101.SeqNumbr) + (@counter)
FROM RM10101
INNER JOIN UpdateData ON RM10101.DocNumbr = UpdateData.DocNumbr 
where rn =@counter   
SET @counter = @counter + 1
end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: OK, Bob.  What have you already tried?  Please share your efforts with us, even if they were not successful.

Comment: (Link 1)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137809/how-to-update-multiple-duplicates-with-different-values-on-the-same-table] (Link 2)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783906/update-one-of-2-duplicates-in-an-sql-server-database-table]

Comment: according to the documentation, the ROW_NUMBER() function was added in SQL Server 2005.  Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response patrick.  I am sorry if I wansn't clear in my post, but I need to update the seqnumbr, based on duplicates in the docnumbr.

Comment: It's SQl 2000.  I am developing on a later version and did not know that about the row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script might fail in case I have sequence like:
('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',903), ('Doc001',904), ('Doc001',905), ('Doc001',905), ('Doc001',905), ('Doc001',910), ('Doc001',910), ('Doc001',915), ('Doc001',915)

The script will give error as below:
*Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

Correct script would be:

```
WHILE (SELECT SUM(X.A) FROM (  SELECT COUNT(*) A FROM Table_1 GROUP BY DocNumber, SeqNumber HAVING count(*) > 1) X) > 0
BEGIN
   With TableAdjusted as (
        select DocNumber, SeqNumber, row_number() over (partition by DocNumber, SeqNumber order by (select NULL)) RowID
        from Table_1
   )

   update A
     set SeqNumber = (B.RowID - 1)*5 + B.SeqNumber
   from TableAdjusted A
   inner join TableAdjusted B
      on A.DocNumber = B.DocNumber and A.SeqNumber = B.SeqNumber and A.RowID = B.RowID 
   where A.RowID > 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting my script. I have updated mine to use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT` which will make the query faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with tb1(id, seqNUm, docNum) as (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeQNumber), DocNumber, SeQNumber From table1
)

update tb1 set docnum=201 where id=2
```

- set id whatever row you want to update

Answer (score 0):

This is a start, I'm having a hard time converting this select query into an update statement.

```
--Build your tally table and sample data

if object_id('dbo.tally') is not null 
        drop table dbo.tally

select top 11000 
    identity(int,1,1) as n
into tally
from master.dbo.syscolumns sc1,
    master.dbo.syscolumns sc2

create table #test_table (
    DocNumber varchar(100),
    SeqNumber int
)

insert into #test_table
select 'Doc001', 900 union all
select 'Doc001', 900 union all
select 'Doc001', 900 union all
select 'Doc001', 903 union all
select 'Doc001', 904

select 
    t1.DocNumber,
    t1.SeqNumber,
    NewSeqNumber =  t1.SeqNumber + (5 * (t.n - 1))
from (
    select
        *,
        c = count(*)
    from #test_table
    group by
        DocNumber, SeqNumber
)t1
inner join tally t
    on t.n <= t1.c

drop table #test_table
```

Answer (score 0):

A bad case would be

> ('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',900), ('Doc001',903),
>   ('Doc001',904), ('Doc001',905), ('Doc001',905), ('Doc001',905),
>   ('Doc001',910), ('Doc001',910), ('Doc001',915), ('Doc001',915)

when you update the rows from 900 to 905 and 910, then you have a case of repetition that didn't exist before.

To solve it, use the following query:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 GROUP BY DocNumber, SeqNumber HAVING count(*) > 1)
BEGIN

   With TableAdjusted as (
        select DocNumber, SeqNumber, row_number() over (partition by DocNumber, SeqNumber order by (select NULL)) RowID
        from Table1
   )

   update A
     set SeqNumber = (B.RowID - 1)*5 + B.SeqNumber
   from TableAdjusted A
   inner join TableAdjusted B
      on A.DocNumber = B.DocNumber and A.SeqNumber = B.SeqNumber and A.RowID = B.RowID 
   where A.RowID > 1
END

select * from Table1 order by DocNumber, SeqNumber
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4922b/3/0)